# Prevent postback for multiple window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, postback

Is it possible to prevent postback for other window opened. Likewise, one window is opened having session values of files, and the second window of the same page doesn't go for postback, so as to maintain the session values. Or if there is any other way i can hold the session values for file attachment even if the page goes for postback.

Comment: No. If multiple tabs can be open with different data in them, then don't use session variables to hold this in your solution, it's clearly not workable. Classic X-Y problem. The answer is to create a better implementation on the server. Session variables should only hold data which applies to the whole session, not to a single page or a single instance of a page.

Comment: Alright, is there any way we can prevent sessions to share across windows. If there is then, this might help. I've tried setting cookies enabled to true, which actually prevents session to share data between windows, but the biggest drawback is that I have to login for each window.

Comment: That's a per-user setting. They can configure whether each browser tab/window opens a new session, or not. It's not something you can control. Like I said, forget about storing your postback data in the session, that's not what the session is for. You need to use some other storage for this information, or re-design your app so you don't have to store anything between these postbacks, whatever they are.